# can we override switch case behaviour like we override operator == with Equatable protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Equatable protocol not called when enum compared in switch case, how does it compare values?

I have implemented below Enum which works perfectly with If Conditions but fails in Switch case, how does switch case compare case values? does it not use == internally?

here is my code

```
    import Foundation

public enum AMSelectionStyle{
    case single
    case multiple
    case any
}

public enum AMCalenderMode{
    case date
    case time
    case dateTime
    case any
    
}

public enum AMNumberType:String{
    case natural = "N" //(also called positive integers, counting numbers, or natural numbers); They are the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}
    case whole = "W" //This is the set of  natural numbers, plus zero, i.e., {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}.
    case integer = "Z" // This is the set of all whole numbers plus all the negatives (or opposites) of the natural numbers, i.e., {… , ⁻2, ⁻1, 0, 1, 2, …}
    case rational = "Q" //This is all the fractions where the top and bottom numbers are integers; e.g., 1/2, 3/4, 7/2, ⁻4/3, 4/1 [Note: The denominator cannot be 0, but the numerator can be].
    case real = "R" //(also called measuring numbers or measurement numbers). This includes all numbers that can be written as a decimal. This includes fractions written in decimal form e.g., 0.5, 0.75 2.35, ⁻0.073, 0.3333, or 2.142857. It also includes all the irrational numbers such as π, √2 etc. Every real number corresponds to a point on the number line.
    case all = "" // all of the above
}
public enum AMInputType:Equatable {
    case list(AMSelectionStyle)
    case number(AMNumberType)
    case calender(AMCalenderMode)
    case freeText
    case boolian
    case picklist
    
   public static func ==(lhs: AMInputType, rhs: AMInputType) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (let .list(a1), let .list(a2)):
            if a1 == .any || a2 == .any {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .single && a2 == .single {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .multiple && a2 == .multiple {
                return true
            }
            return a1 == a2
        case (let .number(a1), let .number(a2)):
            if a1 == .all || a2 == .all {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .natural && a2 == .natural {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .whole && a2 == .whole {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .integer && a2 == .integer {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .rational && a2 == .rational {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .real && a2 == .real {
                return true
            }
            return a1 == a2
        case  (let .calender(a1), let .calender(a2)):
            if a1 == .any || a2 == .any {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .date && a2 == .date {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .time && a2 == .time {
                return true
            }else if a1 == .dateTime && a2 == .dateTime {
                return true
            }
            return a1 == a2
        case (.freeText, .freeText):
            return true
        case (.boolian, .boolian):
            return true
        case (.picklist, .picklist):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

}

func compareEnum(inputType:AMInputType)->Bool{
    switch inputType {
    case .number(.all):
        print("Switch case `number` check Successful")
        return true
    case .calender(.any):
        print("Switch case `calender` check Successful")
        return true
    case .list(.any):
        print("Switch case `list` check Successful")
        return true
    default:
        print("Switch case check Failed")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comparison fails when enum parameter value is different for case number

```
compareEnum(inputType: .number(.real))
```

Comparison succeeded when enum parameters values are same for case number.

```
compareEnum(inputType: .number(.all))
```

If condition succeeds with different enum parameters of case number.

```
if AMInputType.number(.all) == AMInputType.number(.real) {
    print("If Condition `number` check Successful")
}
```

**Edit 1 - Converted enums to implement Equitable as per suggestion by @Tarun Tyagi**

Issue still exits. Equitable protocol not called in Switch case

```
    public enum AMSelectionStyle:Int, Equatable{
    case single
    case multiple
    case any
    
    public static func ==(lhs: AMSelectionStyle, rhs: AMSelectionStyle) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {

        case (.single, .single):
            return true
        case (.single, .multiple):
            return false
        case (.single, .any):
            return true

            
        case (.multiple, .multiple):
            return true
        case (.multiple, .single):
            return false
        case (.multiple, .any):
            return true

            
        case (.any, .any):
            return true
        case (.any, .single):
            return true
        case (.any, .multiple):
            return true
            
        }
    }
}

public enum AMCalenderMode:Int, Equatable{
    case date
    case time
    case dateTime
    case any
    
    public static func ==(lhs: AMCalenderMode, rhs: AMCalenderMode) -> Bool {
        
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        
        case (.date, .date):
            return true
        case (.date, .time):
            return false
        case (.date, .dateTime):
            return false
        case (.date, .any):
            return true

            
        case (.time, .time):
            return true
        case (.time, .date):
            return false
        case (.time, .dateTime):
            return false
        case (.time, .any):
            return true


        case (.dateTime, .dateTime):
            return true
        case (.dateTime, .date):
            return false
        case (.dateTime, .time):
            return false
        case (.dateTime, .any):
            return true
            
        case (.any, .any):
            return true
        case (.any, .date):
            return true
        case (.any, .time):
            return true
        case (.any, .dateTime):
            return true
            
        }
    }
    
}

public enum AMNumberType:String, Equatable{
    case natural = "N" //(also called positive integers, counting numbers, or natural numbers); They are the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}
    case whole = "W" //This is the set of  natural numbers, plus zero, i.e., {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, …}.
    case integer = "Z" // This is the set of all whole numbers plus all the negatives (or opposites) of the natural numbers, i.e., {… , ⁻2, ⁻1, 0, 1, 2, …}
    case rational = "Q" //This is all the fractions where the top and bottom numbers are integers; e.g., 1/2, 3/4, 7/2, ⁻4/3, 4/1 [Note: The denominator cannot be 0, but the numerator can be].
    case real = "R" //(also called measuring numbers or measurement numbers). This includes all numbers that can be written as a decimal. This includes fractions written in decimal form e.g., 0.5, 0.75 2.35, ⁻0.073, 0.3333, or 2.142857. It also includes all the irrational numbers such as π, √2 etc. Every real number corresponds to a point on the number line.
    case all = "" // all of the above
    
    public static func ==(lhs: AMNumberType, rhs: AMNumberType) -> Bool {
        
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        
        case (.natural, .natural):
            return true
        case (.natural, .whole):
            return false
        case (.natural, .integer):
            return false
        case (.natural, .rational):
            return false
        case (.natural, .real):
            return false
        case (.natural, .all):
            return true
            
        case (.whole, .whole):
            return true
        case (.whole, .natural):
            return false
        case (.whole, .integer):
            return false
        case (.whole, .rational):
            return false
        case (.whole, .real):
            return false
        case (.whole, .all):
            return true
          
        case (.integer, .integer):
            return true
        case (.integer, .natural):
            return false
        case (.integer, .whole):
            return false
        case (.integer, .rational):
            return false
        case (.integer, .real):
            return false
        case (.integer, .all):
            return true
            
        case (.rational, .rational):
            return true
        case (.rational, .natural):
            return false
        case (.rational, .whole):
            return false
        case (.rational, .integer):
            return false
        case (.rational, .real):
            return false
        case (.rational, .all):
            return true
            
        case (.real, .real):
            return true
        case (.real, .natural):
            return false
        case (.real, .whole):
            return false
        case (.real, .integer):
            return false
        case (.real, .rational):
            return false
        case (.real, .all):
            return true
            
        case (.all, .all):
            return true
        case (.all, .natural):
            return true
        case (.all, .whole):
            return true
        case (.all, .integer):
            return true
        case (.all, .rational):
            return true
        case (.all, .real):
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift can synthesize `Equatable` conformance for `enum` as long as all it's cases (and their associated values) conform to `Equatable`.

So you get a correct implementation by default, you just need to mark `Equatable` in all the necessary places.

```
import Foundation

public enum AMSelectionStyle: Int, Equatable {
    case single
    case multiple
    case any
}
public enum AMCalenderMode: Int, Equatable {
    case date
    case time
    case dateTime
    case any
}
public enum AMNumberType: String, Equatable {
    case natural = "N"
    case whole = "W"
    case integer = "Z"
    case rational = "Q"
    case real = "R"
    case all = ""
}
public enum AMInputType: Equatable {
    case list(AMSelectionStyle)
    case number(AMNumberType)
    case calender(AMCalenderMode)
    case freeText
    case boolian
    case picklist
}
```

If you run your tests with above code, everything should pass. There is no need to implement your own code for this.

---

#### UPDATE

After a bit more clarification, it is evident that special cases like `any`/`all` need to be handled in a custom implementation. Synthesized implementation won't handle this part.

Here's the updated implementation -

1. Make all enums `Equatable`, handle their special cases `any`/`all` within these type specific implementations.
2. From the final enum that contains other enums as associated types, leverage these type specific implementations as needed.

```
import Foundation

public enum AMSelectionStyle: Int, Equatable {
    case single
    case multiple
    case any
    
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        let any = Self.any.rawValue
        if lhs.rawValue == any || rhs.rawValue == any {
            return true
        } else {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

```
public enum AMCalendarMode: Int, Equatable {
    case date
    case time
    case dateTime
    case any
    
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        let any = Self.any.rawValue
        if lhs.rawValue == any || rhs.rawValue == any {
            return true
        } else {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

```
public enum AMNumberType: String, Equatable {
    case natural = "N"
    case whole = "W"
    case integer = "Z"
    case rational = "Q"
    case real = "R"
    case all = ""
    
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        let all = Self.all.rawValue
        if lhs.rawValue == all || rhs.rawValue == all {
            return true
        } else {
            return lhs.rawValue == rhs.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

```
public enum AMInputType: Equatable {
    case list(AMSelectionStyle)
    case number(AMNumberType)
    case calendar(AMCalendarMode)
    case freeText
    case boolean
    case picklist
    
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.list(let l1), .list(let l2)): return l1 == l2
        case (.number(let n1), .number(let n2)): return n1 == n2
        case (.calendar(let c1), .calendar(let c2)): return c1 == c2
        case (.freeText, .freeText), 
             (.boolean, .boolean),
             (.picklist, .picklist): return true
        default: return false
        }
    }
}
```

##### Test

```
var lhs: AMInputType = .number(.all)
var rhs: AMInputType = .number(.real)
print(lhs == rhs) // prints true
```

Comment: Agreed but this will work only if Equatable protocol is called. but here Equitable protocol is not gets called when Enumused in switch case.

Comment: I have changed to implement all enum to implement Equitable but not working.

Comment: Which one of your tests is failing? What are you expecting it to do? Please share the code where above setup is creating issues.

Comment: OP has some very special requirements so there is no way this can be solved using the default Equatable implementation

Comment: you mean I have to use if else instead of switch case then.

Comment: @TarunTyagi please check above function  `compareEnum` following stamenet return true  but fails in switch case statement. AMInputType.number(.all) == AMInputType.number(.real)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson @DattatrayDeokar Please check the **UPDATE**, this treats `any` / `all` differently according to requirements.

Comment: @TarunTyagi please test your code in switch statement let me know what does it print

Comment: @DattatrayDeokar That expectation itself is wrong. Switch does not rely on enum's `Equatable` implementation. You can still use a switch on an enum that's not marked `Equatable`. So we can't modify how switch works internally. What we can do is - use our `Equatable` implementation for comparison ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

When using a tuple in a switch you can choose to have type of wildcard case's where one side can be anything and this is something you can make use of here to effectively check against `.any` or `.all`

So override `==` so that `.any/.all` works as expected for all 3 enums you use in AMInputType and your comparisons will work.

```
public enum AMSelectionStyle: Equatable{
    case single
    case multiple
    case any

    public static func ==(lhs: AMSelectionStyle, rhs: AMSelectionStyle) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (_, .any):
            return true
        case (.any, _):
            return true
        case (.single, .single),
            (.multiple, .multiple):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

public enum AMCalenderMode: Equatable{
    case date
    case time
    case dateTime
    case any

    public static func ==(lhs: AMCalenderMode, rhs: AMCalenderMode) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (_, .any):
            return true
        case (.any, _):
            return true
        case (.date, .date),
            (.time, .time),
            (.dateTime, .dateTime):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}

public enum AMNumberType:String, Equatable{
    case natural = "N"
    case whole = "W"
    case integer = "Z"
    case rational = "Q"
    case real = "R"
    case all = ""

    public static func ==(lhs: AMNumberType, rhs: AMNumberType) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (_, .all):
            return true
        case (.all, _):
            return true
        case (.natural, .natural),
             (.whole, .whole),
             (.integer, .integer),
             (.rational, .rational),
             (.real, .real):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had raised ticket to apple and received below response from them.

```
This is correct behavior because switch statement doesn’t use `==` operator to match cases, instead it uses `~=`. Try adding `~=` as well for `AMInputType`.
```

But even after overriding operator ~= it dosen't work.

**EDIT**
below is new feedback from apple on issue.

After reviewing your feedback, we have some additional information for you, or some additional information, or action is necessary for this issue:

This is the intended behavior for pattern matching. Swift allows the ~= operator to be used to overload switch-case statements with user-defined semantics when the patterns involved are expressions. Regular patterns will always match using Swift’s built-in pattern matching semantics. The Swift Reference Manual section on pattern matching goes into additional detail about the behavior of the language in these cases: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Patterns.html#grammar_expression-pattern.